# Why coroutine doesn't involve kernel mode

Tags: operating-system, coroutine

When we say "context switch", generally it means switching between execution unit (`struct task_struct` in linux), which involves (from what I know):

1. store and load of registers value
2. TLB shootdown, if two execution units are not of the same process
3. loading for page table
4. user mode to kernel mode switch

I often see words like "coroutine switch doesn't involve mode switch", but I think coroutine switch also involves register switch, why it doesn't need kernel mode?

Answer (score 1):

Because coroutines run in the same address space, with no privilege separation, there's no need to enter kernel mode to change any page tables or other non-user accessable kernel data.

The coroutine switch just needs to save the registers of the current coroutine, and restore the registers of the other coroutine (both being stored in user space), and jump.